# Create image using custom content in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, tinymce-4

I want create a image. That contains images, text with formats. These information user want to give. So what I plan, I place a html editor in web page the user enter any text and upload images, I give one button when user clicks that button based on user gives input in hrml editor I will create image with proper alignment and format. For these method some problem will occurred image left side some white space will appear. I don't know why that was came.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [HTML canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp) is the easiest way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Use NReco.ImageConverter Nuget to create image from Html string. Change Dynamic image using HtmlAgilityPack Nuget

Answer (score 0):

In custom content I have dummy dynamic images, that image replace by user dp when user follow the account thats done on c# so I cannot use html canvas sir